# How to add a root level node in firebase realtime db using console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have a large firebase realtime DB data file. Now when i go to console it mentions that it is read only until i pick a key. Now, I need to add a new node manually to realtime db via console. How do i do that other than writing code or downloading all the data.

tried to go to console and checked it is not possible it seems

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I usually do is type the new node name into the database URL bar in the console:

[image]

So:

1. Go to the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).
2. Click on the URL: <kbd>https://.firebaseio.com/</kbd>.
3. Enter the new node name at the end of the URL.
4. Hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.